# Infamous "Record is too large" when exporting Access table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm struggling with export table from Access 2013. Which itself is imported from SQL Server.

The table has only several number fields, date and currency. That's all. No text fields, large BLOB etc.

Typical row when exported to text file:

```
1,1,1,1,1,2/6/2016 16:02:52,$10.00
```

I'm using Access 2013, export to ODBC with driver "SQL Server native driver 11.0". I've tried another servers and drivers and it is all the same.

With Access 2004 I get error:

```
incorrect syntax near .
```

if table has field of date type.

Comment: more details. Exact Access versions (2004 doesnt exists) ? Exact table structure ? How do you try to export ? Is the table in Access or Linked from SQL server ?

Comment: Sorry, mistypoo, Access 2007 not 2004.

Thomas, It is really several fields as shown in export to text file. Several numbers, date and currency. Why it should be "Record is too large" ?
I just select table, then righ mouse click and select Export->ODBC Database

Comment: Sounds more like a driver issue. Have your tried some kind of dichotomy approach to eliminate possible explanations? For instance you can duplicate the source table in Access, remove some columns and retry, or create a table with the same structure in SQL server and make an export directly in that table, or even create a linked table out of it and copy paste a record from local to linked, etc...